# How to declare a tensor with Eigen without specifying the dimension?

Tags: c++, eigen, tensor

I have a function that takes as input a tensor of dimension n, I have to store this tensor to reuse it later.
However, I don't know in advance the dimension of my tensor.
I would like to do this:

```
//in class.h
Eigen::Tensor<double, N> mytensor;
//in class.cpp 
mytensor = input;
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: You have the wrong tool for the job I'm afraid. `N` can only be specified at compile time. Someone who knows Eigen better than I may be able to offer an alternative.

Comment: Hmmm, I don't think that is possible either but for  `N` will have to be `constexpr` so already known to the compiler at compile-time... For a limited amount of different `N` you might use an `std::variant` like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63920384/9938686).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the parameter `N` is a non-type template parameter, it must be a value known at compile time. This means that you cannot really store an `Eigen::Tensor` with unspecified `N` in a variable, as each instantiation with a different size is a different type.

You can work around this by using containers such as `std::variant` and `std::any`. They make it possible to store an object of a type from either a closed set of types or any type respectively. As an example, you could use `std::any` to create a helper `tensor_holder` class like the following:

```cpp
template <typename T>
class tensor_holder
{
private:
    std::any _held;
    size_t _size;
public:
    template <int N>
    constexpr tensor_holder(Eigen::Tensor<T, N> tensor) :
        _held{std::move(tensor)},
        _size{N}
    {
    }
    constexpr tensor_holder(const tensor_holder&) = default;
    constexpr tensor_holder(tensor_holder&&) = default;
    template <size_t N>
    Eigen::Tensor<T, N>& get()
    {
        return std::any_cast<Eigen::Tensor<T, N>&>(_held);
    }
    template <size_t N>
    const Eigen::Tensor<T, N>& get() const
    {
        return std::any_cast<Eigen::Tensor<T, N>&>(_held);
    }
    constexpr int size() const noexcept
    {
        return _size;
    }
};
```

It stores an `Eigen::Tensor` of any size inside an `std::any`. The member function `get` throws `std::bad_any_cast` if the provided size doesn't match
the real tensor size (note that the limitation of the size being a compile time value doesn't go away).

Assuming you have a small set of possible tensor sizes, you could run different branches inside your function like this:

```cpp
void use_tensor(const tensor_holder<double>& in)
{
    static tensor_holder held = in; // it can be stored for later    

    if (held.size() == 4)
    {
        auto& tensor = held.get<4>();
        tensor(0, 1, 2, 3) = 115.5;
    }
    else if (held.size() == 3)
    {
        // some other logic
    }
}
```

You could also use a `switch` instead of an `if` in this case. This solution is practical only if the number of different tensor sizes you have to support is small. I don't know how you plan to use your tensor, so it's hard for me to say whether this solution is adequate.

Thanks to the converting constructor of class `tensor_holder`, you can call the function by simply providing it an `Eigen::Tensor` with any size:

```cpp
use_tensor(Eigen::Tensor<double, 3>{});
```

([godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/T9bs99qja))